# How to disable link tracking in emails?

Tags: links

We are having a problem with the click through links in the email templates.  I need to see if it works if link tracking is disabled.  Where can I turn that off?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to answer this without knowing your CiviCRM version - but in 4.6+, there should be a "Tracking" tab when you go to **Mailings » New Mailing**.  See screenshot below.  You can uncheck *Track Click-Throughs*.  Note that this is a per-mailing setting!

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  That is what I was looking for.  Now I will start a new topic on how to fix the link tracking problem, now that I have confirmed that is where the issue is coming from.